# Time complexity of russian peasant multiplication algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, multiplication

I want to know that what is the time complexity of this piece of code which is Russian peasant Implementation

```
unsigned long long int russian(unsigned long long int a, unsigned long long int b) {
    unsigned long long int res = 0;
     while (b > 0) {
        if (b & 1)
            res = res + a;
        a <<= 1;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return res % mod;
}
```

As far as my knowledge i think its time complexity is either **lg2b** or **lg2a**(depending upon our choice of **a** or **b**) .Any expert comment?

Comment: @EugeneK So it will be a clever decision to choose which number is to get half(as it decides time complexity)..isn't it?

Comment: Why not test it? Take a big and small number, multiply them and see how many iterations it took to multiply. Then swap the order and see if one was faster than the other.

Comment: @EugeneK just for future readers--There is no significant difference after changing position of the numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity of the piece of code you supplied is, of course, `O(1)`, because there is an upper bound on how long it can take and will never exceed that upper bound on any inputs.

Presumably, that's not the answer to the question you actually mean to ask. There are actually several *different* things you might be actually interested in, and they all actually have different answers.

(also, since you seem to be trying to do a modular multiply, you really should be reducing all relevant quantities *inside* the loop so that you don't overflow, and so that you can use `-` instead of `%`)

---

You might be interested in having a precise estimate of the wall-clock time. Obtaining this will actually require gathering some empirical data, but it will probably look something like

```
A + B bitlength(b) + C popcount(b)
```

(`popcount` is the number of `1`s in the binary expansion) for some constants `A`, `B`, and `C`. However, CPU hardware is actually rather complicated, and it might actually be extremely involved to get a good estimate for the third term above, since branch prediction hardware might do some odd things.

And `A`, `B`, and `C` probably aren't even constants; they will depend to some extent on whether this function gets inlined, and the sort of code surrounding the places where it's used.

---

Now, you might want a more abstract answer where `b` can be of arbitrary size, rather than constrained to be the size of an `unsigned long long`, and want to count the number of arithmetic operations. This is very clearly just the bit length of `b`, or as the comments indicate, `O(lg(b))`. (where `lg` is the log base 2)

---

Now, you might actually be interested not just in the arithmetic operations, but their *cost*. And might be interested in `a` being of arbitrary size rather than constrained to be an `unsigned long long`. A useful unit of measure would be bit operations. e.g. doing a left-shift by 1 on an `N`-bit number ought to cost `O(N)` bit operations.

I'm pretty sure the loop works out to `O(lg(a)lg(b)+lg(b)^2)` bit operations. (this doesn't include the `%` operation you do afterwards)